# Тестирование In-app Billing в андроид

Tags: in-app-purchases, android

Так получилось, что свою кредитную карточку я недавно закрыл, и теперь не знаю, как можно проверить работу in-app purchase от гугла. Согласно документации "Draft Apps are No Longer Supported", нужно публиковать приложение перед тестированием (как альфа-версию, к примеру).

Но есть несколько проблем:
1) Мне нужно оттестировать подписки "Subscriptions" - насколько я понял из документации, гугл вообще не предоставляет каких-либо средств для тестирования данного типа покупок.

"Test purchases are only supported for in-app products, not for in-app subscriptions."

Как все-таки проверить работоспособность подписки?

2) При тестировании in-app purchase гугл все же позволяет сделать тестовую покупку, но для этого нужно иметь кредитную карту (или дебетовую) - на все попытки ввести фейковую гугл говорил, мол, неправильный номер карты. Вводил даже еще работующую визу, но карточка закрытая без возможности делать интернет-платежы - также говорит неправильный номер карты. 
Вопрос, собственно: можно все-таки как-то провести тестовый платеж (ведь деньги не должны взыматься) без открытия карты в банке (использовать фейковую или как-то иначе)?

3) И последний: гугл предлагает встроенные тестовые SKU id типа "android.test.purchased", 
но при попытке провести покупку возвращается ответ с пустым полем подписи - в результате ошибка верификации платежа. (Приложение подписанное release-сертификатом (тем, что в плей-маркет загружено), флаг debug="false"). Кто знает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: По второму вопросу - можно **QIWI** юзать - там можно пользоваться фэйковой кредиткой, привязанном к счёту, зареганному на симку.

Answer (score 1):

1. Тестировать подписки также возможно.
2. Для тестирования к аккаунту должен быть привязан настоящий способ оплаты. Это может быть кредитка а также сим-карта некоторых операторов. Например beeline или megafon
3. Для успешного совершения тестовой покупки надо соблюсти множество условий. Вот тут они описаны: [“Этот продукт не продается” Billing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609)