# "Этот продукт не продается" Billing

Tags: android

"Этот продукт не продается" при появлении кнопки покупки, что не так?. Ключ добавил, ключ добавил, приложение в релиз залил теперь она в маркете, но кнопка все равно не работает, что делать7

APK Залит в релизе, Можно найти в маркете название АвтоПро
ID покупок выбрал контролируется Google, название такое `buy_gold`

```
    public class Vip extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{
    BillingProcessor bp;
    String KEY="";
    String SKU="buy_gold";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vip);
        ((TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tb_textView)).setText("");
        ((ImageView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tb_imageView)).setOnClickListener(this);
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tb_imageView:
                bp.purchase(Vip.this,SKU);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String s, TransactionDetails transactionDetails) {
        Log.e("asd",s+"  "+transactionDetails.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int i, Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {

    }
}
```

В манифесте прописал Billing, в градле подключил эту либу

Comment: Тут миллион причин может быть. Конкретизируйте вопрос. apk залит в режиме релизном? apk не в дебаг моде? id покупок точно верный? id покупок используете точно не тестовые?

Comment: Добавил, а что значит id покупок не тестовые?

Comment: наверное потому что вы залили в плей подписанный файл апк, а в устройстве установлена апк которая не подписана сертификатом(т.е. прямо из IDE вы скомпилировали)..

Comment: Нет качал из маркета

Comment: @Suvitruf,Ну так что? есть идеи какие - нибудь

Comment: @xTIGRx вы админской консоли в GP какие id для покупок вбивали? Их и используете?

Comment: У меня точно такая ситуация, Вам удалось решить данную проблему?
НАпишите как Вы это сделали.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Для успешной тестовой покупки надо:

1. Выложенное в маркет приложение в бета-версии.
2. Созданный продукт для покупки
3. Список юзеров-тестировщиков в консоли.
4. Эти юзеры-тестировщики должны принять участие в бета-тесте путём перехода по ссылке из консоли.
5. приложение должно быть подписано релизным ключом, идентичным тому, коим подписана версия в маркете.
6. Версия приложения на девайсе (`versionCode` в `build.gradle`) должна совпадать с  версией приложения, опубликованного в маркете.

Comment: мне помогла смена `versionCode`, премного благодарен

Comment: а мне публикация, если запрос делать установив со Студии, то читает, но при выполнении дает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Для тестирования корректного запуска GUI покупки достаточно релизного ключа И той же версии versionCode в build.gradle, что и релиз.

У меня следующие настройки:

Идем в **File** -> **Project Structure** -> (слева в **Modules**) **app** -> (сверху) **Signing**:

Здесь заведена конфигурация. В ней выбран ключ, которым я подписываю релизную версию приложения.

Идем в (сверху) **Build Types**, выбираем **release**. Справа в списке есть опция **Signing Config**. Установлена конфигурация с названием из Signing.

Таким образом, при запуске в **Build Variant - Release**, приложение автоматически подписывается релизным ключом.

Далее проверяем, чтобы **versionCode** был такой же, что и действующий ныне релиз (рабочая версия в Управлении версиями в Play Developer Console). Не больше и не меньше.

При таких настройках я просто жму **Run "app" (Shift+F10)** и имею приложение на тестовом девайсе с рабочим **launchPurchaseFlow()**. То есть, он запускается, рисует свое окошко, получает данные о стоимости, названии и т.д. Никаких "Этот продукт не продается" при том, что не нужно ничего обновлять в альфа и бета каналах маркета. Ткнул в Андроид Студио и оно работает.

**Покупку совершать не рекомендуется!** При таких настройках вы честно купите свой продукт. Но если ваша версия лежит в бета, то ваши бета тестировщики могут тратить любые деньги в приложении - все вернется обратно на карту. **Это я не проверял, так в гайдах написано.**

Comment: Вам следует давать более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Так же удалите все аккаунты с устройства, кроме тестовых. Это мне помогло