# Способы тестрирования in-app покупок на реальных товарах

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Я провел тесты на статических запросах,  в ответ на которые Google возвращает не полную информацию о покупке, к примеру, нет цифровой подписи. Теперь я хочу протестить полный функционал, так как продукты в полной мере протестировать не получается, а подписки и промокоды вобще нельзя. И единственный способ это сделать, на сколько я понимаю, это купить продукт за реальные деньги, а потом делать его возврат? Или есть еще какие-то способы проверить работу приложения на реальных продуктах в `Google Play` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно тестировать реальные покупки. В этом случае их цена будет указана как 0руб и, если это подписка, она будет иметь срок всегда 1 день. Необходимые условия для тестирования можно найти в [официальном руководстве](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) и кратко тут на [русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609)

Comment: Отлично. А если у меня открытое альфа-тестирование, я даю ссылку на приложение тестировщику, то он может сделать покупку, при условии что у него привязана карточка, но за покупку с него денег не снимет, правильно?  И еще цена 0 руб. - это цена которая будет ему отображаться, или цена которую я должен указать?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, на счёт открытого тестирования не знаю - не пробовал. В закрытом бета-тесте надо обязательно внести мыло тестера в список тестеров и подписаться ему надо на бета-тест. А 0р будет отображаться как сумма списания независимого от того, какова реальная цена. Также не обязательно картой оплачивать - некоторые операторы позволяют списывать со счёта симки

Comment: т.е. стоит сделать закрытое бета-тестирование  и это позволит мне тестить реальные покупки, без снятия денег с карточки, я правильно понимаю!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, да, я так делал и так оно работает. Возможно так можно и для открытого теста сделать, но я не пробовал.

Comment: а не могли бы вы мне разяснить эту строку с документации:  After you publish your app to an alpha or beta channel, your testers need to opt-in to your app’s alpha or beta test using the provided opt-in URL before they can make test purchases.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, в `Файлы APK`, будет поле `URL регистрации`, там будет значение вида `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/ПАКЕТ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ`. Тестерам надо перейти по этой ссылке и нажать `Принять участие в бета-тесте`. Без этого тестовые покупки работать не будут.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Я попробовал сделать, так как вы описали, но у меня цена при покупке была не 0 грн а столько солько я указал в консоли для этого продукта + у меня сняло деньги с карты, не подскажите что я могу не так делать?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Вы делали покупку с гугло-акка, коий записан как тестер в консоли разработчика? И этот акк переходил по ссылке из бета-теста консоли и нажимал на "участвовать в тестировании"?

Comment: да, с аккаунта, и перейдя по ссылке мне предложило  установить приложение или отказаться от тестирования, кнопки "участвовать в тестировании" там не было,  я так понимаю что  перейдя по ссылке я автоматически согласился стать тестером.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, странно... У меня всё работало... Проверьте ещё раз все акки, наличие бета-теста, попробуйте другой акк. Правда, может быть, не для всех стран есть такая возможность...

Comment: Я до этого делал все так как вы советовали тут и в другом вашем ответе, все правильно, кроме одной детали  о которой я до этого нигде не слышал, в Developer Console нажно было  добавить аккаунт тестировщика еще в " тестирование лицензии" , а я добавил его просто во вкладке с бета-тестом

Comment: @KirillStoianov, т.е. после этого у вас заработало? Я не слышал ни про какие "тестирования лицензий"

Comment: Да, после того как добавил тестирование лицензии мне начали в диалоговом окне писать (что  деньги снимать не будут), а до этого такого небыло

Answer (score 1):

Все шаги которые нужны для того, что бы протестировать покупки на реальных товарах (но без списания денег со счета).
Практические шаги можно найти [в ответе @ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/191718), я их на всякий случай продублирую и добавлю пункт 7*, когда я выполнил 
все шаги кроме 7 - все работало, но снимало деньги, деньги снимать перестало после того как я выполнил пункт 7*.

1. Загрузить бета-версию приложения в Google Play
2. Приложение должно быть подписано  релизным ключем
3. Добавить реальные продукты которые можно купить для данного приложени
4. Добавить тестировщиков
5. Тестировщик должен перейти по ссылке(принять участие в тестировании) и установить приложение по предложеной ссылке.
6. Версии приложения на девайсе и в GooglePlay должны совпадать
7. - В GooglePlay Developer Console перейти в меню "Настройки" и там добавить аккаунт тестровщика в форме "Тестирование лицензии"

Доп. инфо

https://ejaw.helpdocs.com/programmers/google-play-game-center