# Как отлаживать приложение с использованием релиз ключа?

Tags: android-studio, отладка, google-play, android-billing, keystore

Пытаюсь прикрутить к приложению In-App-Billing. Загрузил app для бетатеста Но возникли проблемы с дебагом. Когда локально на компе компилю и пытаюсь тестировать то получаю сообщенние `this version of the application is not configured for billing`. Такого не происходит если app загружать с магазина. Но я же не могу каждую правку закачивать в магазин...Собственно необходимо как-то при дебаги чтобы as генерила и загружала на телефон apk c ключем релиза. Если есть какой-то более лояльный метод посоветуйте. Спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего вам хватит вот этих 7 пунктов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609 Или ваш вопрос в том как подписать приложение релизным ключом при запуске из студии и при этом так, чтобы в логах что-то показывалось?

Comment: Второй вариант. Это безумие при малейшей правке постоянно загружать в магазин. Я хочу локально тестить. В связке AS=>USB=>Телефон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы протестировать работу покупок в маркете [надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609):

1. Залить версию приложения с подключёнными либами и разрешениями в бета-тест
2. Создать в консоли товары.
3. Записать в консоль е-мейлы тестировщиков
4. Разослать им ссылку на бета-тест по которой они должны пройти и принять её

Далее чтобы собирать из студии новые версии и что-то изменять/тестировать надо настроить подписывание АПК файла релизным ключом - вот тут написано как:

[Можно ли запускать приложение из IDE с подписью release ключем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564538/17609)

Также очень важно чтобы версия сборки в студии совпадала с версией приложения в маркете.

Чтобы видеть выхлоп в логах надо в манифесте прописать у тега `application` - `android:debuggable="true"`. И не забыть сменить его на `false`, т.к. в маркет нельзя заливать приложения с  `true`

Comment: Какжется это(IDE с подписью release ключем) то что необходимо. Спасибо.