# In-App Purchase в Activity по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Скопировал классы из TrivialDrive как надо, aidl файл скопировал, но вот написать чтобы все верно работало так и не получается... Гугловскую документацию читал, ничего особо не понял... Скопировал чей-то код по покупкам и пытаюсь разобрать. Буду очень благодарен тому, кто доходчиво объяснит как это всё должно работать.

Activity с покупками:

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    Button buyAddOff;
    public static final String PREF = "myprefs";
    public static final String COLOR_PRE = "colorPref";
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    ServiceConnection mServiceConn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                       IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };
    bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND").setPackage("com.android.vending"),
            mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int theme = sharedPrefs.getInt(COLOR_PRE, 0);
    setColor(theme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    setTitle("О приложении");
    buyAddOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buyAddOff);
    buyAddOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add("AddOff");

            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            try
            {
                Bundle skuDetail = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
                Log.d("Billing", "Response Received");

                int billingResponse = skuDetail.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (billingResponse == 0)
                {
                    //Get list of IAP's to purcase - NOT NEEDED
                    ArrayList responseList = skuDetail.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    Log.d("Billing", "Response");

                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
                            "mypurchase", "inapp", "");

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                            1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                            Integer.valueOf(0));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Billing", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли про onActivityResult. А так там много нюансов. Опишите что из ожидаемого у вас не происходит или не получается. Так то в доке всё описано

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Никаких вылетов не наблюдал, но при нажатии на кнопку "Отключить рекламу" ничего не происходит. а должно высвечиваться окошко с предложением купить продукт

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не выложено приложение в стор. Или ещё чего. Вот список необходимых магический пассов при тестировании покупок: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб возможно, что вы правы. У меня просто версия немного не та в сторе. Сейчас допилю одну функцию и попробую заново InAppBilling поставить, т.к. когда уже понимаю примерно что и куда, то меньше шансов сделать глупые ошибки)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться моим методом. Его я описал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770241/22239).

Метод основан на библиотеке из `GitHub` - `In-App-Billing-v3` от `Anjlab`

[ознакомиться с библиотекой](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) | [ознакомиться с Anjlab](https://github.com/anjlab)

**Будьте внимательны!**

Я описал работу биллинга в классе, расширенного  `Fragment`, Вам нужно же в `Activity`, поэтому, как минимум, у Вас вместо `getActivity()` будет `this`. И иные методы обратного вызова с инициализацией `View` Вашего экрана.