# Тестовый продукт для тестирование подписки на Android в Unity3D

Tags: java, android, c#, unity3d

Создаю подписку для `Android` в первый раз, на `IOS` есть возможность использовать тестовый продукт даже для `подписки`, есть ли тестовый продукт для тестирования **`подписки`** на `Android` платформе ?, и где его взять?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как таковых, специальных тестовых подписок не существует. Но можно тестировать на обычных

1. Создаёте продукт-подписку
2. Выкладываете приложение в альфа/бэта тест.
3. Прописываете мыло юзера-тестировщика в консоли в 2 местах (бета тест и какие-то общие настройки аккаунта)
4. Юзер идёт по ссылке на бета-тест приложения, соглашается и качает с маркета бета версию.
5. В ней он может за 0р купить любую подписку в приложении. Она будет возобновляться каждый день.

Вот ещё вопросы по теме:

1. [“Этот продукт не продается” Billing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528621/17609)
2. [Тестирование In-app Billing в андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600212/17609)

Comment: а что значит фраза "Она будет возобновляться каждый день."?

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, это значит, что длительность всех подписок - 1 день. Через день после покупки она бдет автоматически продлена. Но это раньше. Теперь (в течении месяца) гугл сделает так, что длительность подписки вообще будет меньше часа для годовой и ещё меньше для всех остальных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ещё вопрос - вот к примеру я в настройках подписки выставлю бесплатный период 7 дней. Пользователь подписался, а через три дня отписался (отменил подписку). Правильно ли я понимаю, что ещё 4 дня у пользователя будет подписка?

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, да, всё верно